# How to get rid of the "Loading from pre-bundled file" message?

Tags: react-native

After the launchscreen, but before app is loaded, there's a "Loading from pre-bundled file" message that appears at the top of the screen for just a few hundred milliseconds. I don't mind this in development but I still see this message while running on my phone. Here's how I created the bundle. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
react-native bundle --platform ios --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output App/main.jsbundle --resetCache
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Change Build Configuration to release

To [disable the developer menu](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#debugging-react-native-apps) and therefore your mentioned message, you should change your `Build Configuration` to `Release`.

> For iOS open your project in Xcode and select Product → Scheme → Edit Scheme... (or press ⌘ + <). Next, select Run from the menu on the left and change the Build Configuration to Release.

Comment: This is the right answer. However, do you know how to do this for Android?

Answer (score 0):

Also you can run this

```
react-native bundle --entry-file index.ios.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
```

And then change in xcode class AppDelegate.m

```
 //jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];

  jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

Comment: This is not needed anymore. (adjusting the jsCodeLocation) it is an unnecessary complication.