# React Native iOS show Downloading JavaScript bundle

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

When I launch app on iPhone, I get this message

> Downloading JavaScript bundle...

on top of screen. It take about 2 minutes. (see image below)

How can i hide this message and improve performance of this step ?

[image]

Comment: You can't (okay maybe, buy a faster phone / internet :P). When you build your app in release mode it will not have this phase, but of course you can't debug in release mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is natural in dev mode. When you release the app this will not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal developer mode. 
You need to import your project into XCODE and get the release `ipa` file with your developer account. Otherwise running with `react-native run-ios` command will load js bundle each time you open the application.

Answer (score 0):

Change Build Configuration solve this issue.

> For iOS open your project in Xcode and select Product → Scheme → Edit Scheme... (or press ⌘ + <). Next, select Run from the menu on the left and change the Build Configuration to Release.
>   From : 
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/34426258/6470308